# Ruby: gems to manage config files

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to create a dot file to hold the configuration for an app I've created.

I've seen this https://github.com/mattdbridges/dotify which is no longer maintained and this https://github.com/GRoguelon/DotConfig  which appears to still be in alpha.

It seems I'd be best off managing this manually (i.e. writing the code myself).

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I recommend using YAML (http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html) to write, load, and read your config files.